# Given two posets $\preccurlyeq$, prove that the following relation $R$ using both of them is transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

We're given the following relation $R$ for two posets $(S_1, \preccurlyeq_1)$ and $(S_2, \preccurlyeq_2)$:

For $a_1,b_1 \in S_1$ and $a_2, b_2 \in S_2$:

$(a_1, a_2)R(b_1,b_2) \Leftrightarrow (a_1 \preccurlyeq_1 b_1 \land a_1 \neq b_1) \lor (a_2 \preccurlyeq_2 b_2 \land a_1 = b_1)$

I can see that this relation is both reflexive and antisymmetric, but what about transitivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose $(a_1,a_2)R(b_1,b_2)$ and $(b_1,b_2)R(c_1,c_2)$ for some $a_1, b_1, c_1 \in S_1$ and $a_2,b_2,c_2 \in S_2$. Now we have four possible cases: 
$1)$ We have $(a_1 \preccurlyeq_1 b_1 \land a_1 \neq b_1)$ and $(b_1 \preccurlyeq_1 c_1 \land b_1 \neq c_1)$, hence it follows by the transitivity of $\preccurlyeq_1$ that $(a_1 \preccurlyeq_1 c_1 \land a_1 \neq c_1)$, i.e. $(a_1,a_2)R(c_1,c_2)$. 
$2)$ We have $(a_1 \preccurlyeq_1 b_1 \land a_1 \neq b_1)$ and $(b_2 \preccurlyeq_2 c_2 \land b_1 = c_1)$, hence it follows $(a_1 \preccurlyeq_1 c_1 \land a_1 \neq c_1)$ since $b_1=c_1$ i.e. $(a_1,a_2)R(c_1,c_2)$.
$3)$ We have $(a_2 \preccurlyeq_2 b_2 \land a_1 = b_1)$ and $(b_1 \preccurlyeq_1 c_1 \land b_1 \neq c_1)$, hence it follows $(a_1 \preccurlyeq_1 c_1 \land a_1 \neq c_1)$  since $a_1=b_1$, i.e. $(a_1,a_2)R(c_1,c_2)$. 
$4)$ We have $(a_2 \preccurlyeq_2 b_2 \land a_1 = b_1)$ and $(b_2 \preccurlyeq_2 c_2 \land b_1 = c_1)$, hence by transitivity of $\preccurlyeq_2$ and $a_1=b_1=c_1$ we have $(a_2 \preccurlyeq_2 c_2 \land a_1 = c_1)$, i.e. $(a_1,a_2)R(c_1,c_2)$. 
This proves that $R$ is transitive.

Comment: I've thought about that initially, but I stopped after the first case: how exactly do you prove that $a_1 \neq c_1$? Yes, we do know $a_1 \neq b_1$ and $b_1 \neq c_1$, but how does that imply $a_1 \neq c_1$?

Comment: Because you have  $a_1 \preccurlyeq_1 b_1 \preccurlyeq_1 c_1$ and $a_1 \neq b_1$

Comment: Let $a_1 = 1, b_1 = 2, c_1 = 1$. Also let $a_1 \preccurlyeq_1 b_1 \preccurlyeq c_1$ and $a_1 \neq b_1 \land b_1 \neq c_1$. Am I missing something, or do you really want to say $a_1 \neq c_1 \Leftrightarrow 1 \neq 1$?

Comment: If $a_1=c_1$ you will have $c_1 \preccurlyeq_1 a_1 \preccurlyeq_1 b_1 \preccurlyeq_1 c_1$ and in particular $c_1 \preccurlyeq_1 b_1$. But you have also $b_1 \preccurlyeq_1 c_1$ and this leads to $b_1=c_1$, a contradiction